# return a class instead of argument in stream().map() NOT DUPLICATE

Tags: java, dictionary, java-stream

working with a given class like this

```
class MyClass{
private String name;
MyClass(String name){this.name=name;}
public String getName(){return this.name;}
}
```

with a collection like this

```
List<MyClass>cl = Arrays.asList(
            new MyClass("Mike"),
            new MyClass("Luke"),
            new MyClass("John"),
            new MyClass("Mike"),
            new MyClass("Luke")
            );
```

i am able to have a String list of unique names

```
List<String>uniqueNames = cl.stream().map(a->a.getName()).distinct()
.collect(Collectors.toList());
```

what i want is *MyClass* list instead of a String list but i don't get how to return *MyClass* instead of the String from *.getName()* inside the stream

edit: that "duplicate" just explains the distinct function, i put *.distinct()* just as an example, i may want all the classes with names that begins with "M" for example. I want to know the best way to return a class object when i check the predicate with *.map()* or something equivalent instead of using a filter.

Comment: I suggest you add `equals(Object)` and `hashCode()` to MyClass then you will be able to add them to a set which is a more natural collection if you have distinct elements.

Comment: Nevertheless it's a duplicate (or you badly formulated your question). Will `cl.stream().map(a->a.getName()).distinct().map(MyClass::new).collect(toList())` satisfy you?